# How to check if a file contains plain text?

Tags: python

I have a folder full of files and I want to search some string inside them. The issue is that some files may be zip, exe, ogg, etc.
Can I check somehow what kind of file is it so I only open and search through txt, PHP, etc. files.
I can't rely on the file extension.

Comment: Can you just call out to `file`?  It covers a lot of types.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Python interface](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) to [libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) to identify file formats.

```
>>> import magic
>>> f = magic.Magic(mime=True)
>>> f.from_file('testdata/test.txt')
'text/plain'
```

For more examples, see the [repo](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic).

Answer (score 10):

Use Python's `mimetypes` library:

```
import mimetypes
if mimetypes.guess_type('full path to document here')[0] == 'text/plain':
    # file is plaintext
```

Comment: mimetypes uses the file's filename.ext to determine the file content. It is really easy to spoof that by renaming a file. On a *nix system using the "file" command is safer because it looks inside the file itself to see what the contents look like. "file" can be spoofed too but at least it looks at the contents. Something like python-magic, mentioned by Sinan below, would be safer. For more info do a "man file" and "man magic" on *nix.

Comment: It's interesting that the OP specifically said he can't rely on the file extension, then marked correct an answer that only looks at the file extension...

Answer (score 2):

try something like this :

```
def is_binay_file(filepathname):
    textchars = bytearray([7,8,9,10,12,13,27]) + bytearray(range(0x20, 0x7f)) + bytearray(range(0x80, 0x100))
    is_binary_string = lambda bytes: bool(bytes.translate(None, textchars))

    if is_binary_string(open(filepathname, 'rb').read(1024)):
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

use the method like this :

```
is_binay_file('<your file path name>')
```

This will return True if file is of binary type and False if it is of text - it should be easy to convert this to reflect your needs, fx. make a function `is_text_file` - I leave that up to you

Comment: Will it work on a text file containing Unicode/emojis?

Comment: @Dilawar I have not tested it on unicode

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux you can parse the output of the `file` command-line tool.