# Implementing Error handling within Filedialog Python 3

Tags: python, file, dialog

I'm trying to display an error within my program only IF a invalid file is selected within the file dialog function. I have tried using `try` and `except` and although it works, the error is displayed even if a valid file is selected. I want an error to be displayed only if a invalid file is selected within filedialog e.g. ".exe" file type. Below is a sample of my code

```
def SelectFile():
global FileSelection                                                                                                                                                                                
FileSelection = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("*.txt files", ".txt"), ("All Files", "*.*"), ("*.ARLIDIO-IS-SEXY files")))                             
if  FileSelection:
    try:
        self.settings["template"].set(FileSelection)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Invalid File Type Please Select A Valid Text File")
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some space and indentation errors in the code, you might want to fix that. And when it comes to the try / except part, what you are trying is:

```
self.settings["template"].set(FileSelection)
```

So if the except is triggered every time, there is something wrong with that code. Without knowing the context of what that is, I can only guess that it should be this instead:

```
self.settings["template"] = FileSelection
```

This does not check in any way if it is a txt file or not. Read [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472221/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-textfile) to see solutions for checking if it is a text file. If you want to limit the filetypes to only open `.txt` files, you could always remove the other filetypes.